# Need find query for dynamic multiple nested collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, filter, find, aggregation

I need to find collections based nested on values.But my collection having dynamic values . See below code. In which image name keys are dynamic ( _DSC9691.jpg , _DSC9514.JPG ) and " key1 " is dynamic items. Now I need to find collection based on component, material, Subtype

```
 { 
"_id" : ObjectId("5ce2df8498f10b276cb466c4"), 
"num" : "1", 
"lat" : "39.941436099965", 
"lon" : "-86.0691700063581", 
"images" : {
    "_DSC9691.jpg" : {
        "key1" : {
            "component" : "Sleeve", 
            "condition" : "", 
            "sub_type" : {
                "Auto Sleeve" : true
            }, 
            "material" : "", 
            "misc" : ""
        }
    }
}}

{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5ce2df8498f10b276cb466c7"), 
"num" : "4", 
"lat" : "39.9413828961847", 
"lon" : "-86.0715084495015", 
"images" : {
    "_DSC9554.JPG" : {

    }, 
    "_DSC9514.JPG" : {

    }, 
    "_DSC9622.JPG" : {

    } 


}}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Nagendran you won't be able to perform those operations because the nested document that you want to watch isn't named properly. I suggest you to rename that field using a common name and try to use the code bellow. Also remember to **not use** blank spaces on field names like "Auto Sleeve".

**Object:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce2df8498f10b276cb466c7"), 
    "num" : "4", 
    "lat" : "39.9413828961847", 
    "lon" : "-86.0715084495015", 
    "images" : [
            {
                "name" : "some name",
                "key":
                {
                    "component" : "Sleeve", 
                    "condition" : "", 
                    "sub_type" : {
                        "Auto_Sleeve" : true
                    }, 
                    "material" : "", 
                    "misc" : ""
                }, 
            },
            {
                "name" : "some name 2",
                "key":
                {
                    "component" : "Sleeve 2", 
                    "condition" : "", 
                    "sub_type" : {
                        "Auto_Sleeve" : true
                    }, 
                    "material" : "", 
                    "misc" : ""
                }, 
            },
        ]
}
```

**Query:**

```
db.collection.find({
  "images.key.sub_type.Auto_Sleeve": true
})
```

If you want you can use aggregation framework to filter inside the "images" nested document.

To get a litle bit more information you can access:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

https://university.mongodb.com/

Comment: thanks Glenn. I couldn't change the schema of the collection. Because I am importing this schema from other source.